# Prevent two methods to share the same code?

Tags: c++, function, class, c++11, methods

In my .cpp file for `IntMatrix` class, I wrote the following code:

```
IntMatrix& IntMatrix::operator+=(int num) {
    int matrix_size=size();
    for (int i=0;i<matrix_size;i++)
    {
        data[i]+=num;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

As you can see both `operator+` functions have exactly the same code, how may I prevent that and limit code duplications? (Can I use one to call the other)

Note: I'm working with C++11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can just call the `operator+` with a flipped order:

```
IntMatrix operator+(int scalar, const IntMatrix &matrix) {
  return matrix + scalar;  // calls operator+(const IntMatrix &matrix, int scalar) 
}
```

Also, for `operator+` taking an `IntMatrix` as the first argument, you can take the argument by value, since you are making a copy of the `IntMatrix` anyway:

```
IntMatrix operator+(IntMatrix matrix, int scalar) {
    matrix += scalar;
    return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215873/discussion-on-answer-by-cigien-prevent-two-methods-to-share-the-same-code).

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid one indirection and implement both `operator+` in terms of `operator+=` without code duplication with:

```
IntMatrix operator+(IntMatrix matrix, int scalar);

IntMatrix operator+(int scalar, IntMatrix matrix);

IntMatrix operator+(IntMatrix matrix, int scalar) {
    return matrix+=scalar;
}

IntMatrix operator+(int scalar, IntMatrix matrix) {
    return matrix+=scalar;
}
```